# matlab multi-objective optimization for feature selection

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
Here are my 4 functions for minimization
Objective functions = 4
variables = 13
non-equality constraints = 2
equality constraints = 4
Objective Description:

    function [f]=task1(x)
    f(1)=15*x(1)+20*x(2)+30*x(3)+25*x(4)+40*x(5)+35*x(6)+35*x(7)+50*x(8)+20*x(9)+23*x(10)+30*x(11)+45*x(12)+50*x(13);
    f(2)=5*x(1)+3*x(2)+4*x(3)+5*x(4)+4*x(5)+6*x(6)+5*x(7)+8*x(8)+5*x(9)+3*x(10)+2*x(11)+7*x(12)+6*x(13);
    f(3)=6*x(1)+4*x(2)+2*x(3)+2*x(4)+3*x(5)+4*x(6)+4*x(7)+4*x(8)+2*x(9)+3*x(10)+3*x(11)+4*x(12)+3*x(13);
    f(4)=2048*x(1)+1024*x(2)+256*x(3)+512*x(4)+256*x(5)+512*x(6)+1024*x(7)+1024*x(8)+512*x(9)+512*x(10)+256*x(11)+1024*x(12)+512*x(13);

%Equality constraints
c(1,1)=x(1)+x(2)-1;        %from x(1) and x(2), only one should be selected
c(1,2)=x(3)+x(4)+x(7)-1;   %from x(3), x(4) and x(7), only one should be selected
c(1,3)=x(5)+x(6)+x(7)-1;   %from x(5), x(6) and x(7), only one should be selected
c(1,4)=x(12)+x(13)-1;      %from x(12) and x(13), only one should be selected. 
%non-equality constraint
c(1,5)=x(8)-1;              %x(8) is optional non-equality constraint
c(1,6)=-x(9)-x(10)-x(11)+1; %from x(9), x(10) and x(11) at least one should be selected.
```

please check my given constraints these are OK?

Can you please guide me about lower bound and higher bound values.
I have tried 0 lower bound for all variables and 1 higher bound value for all variables. 0 means not selected and 1 means selected but i am not getting desired results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I suspect you want to add the requirement that x(i) are binary variables (i.e. they can only assume 0 or 1).